# VB.NET with MS SQL - Login Form Error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a login form using vb.net and trying to link with MSSQL.
However I got an error message at below after I input the correct username and password and click on the login button.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

and then it highlighted the following line:

> conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX-HP;Initial Catalog=eagleeyes;Integrated Security=True"

Below is my full code and wish someone can give me some hints.. Thank you.

```
Public Class frm_loginform

Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click
    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If txt_usename.Text = "" Or txt_pwd.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Both fields was supply
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX-HP;Initial Catalog=eagleeyes;Integrated Security=True"

        Try
            'conn.Open()
            'MsgBox("Susscess")

            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE e_name='" & txt_usename.Text & "' AND e_pwd= '" & txt_pwd.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                frm_MainForm.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
                ' Throw an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                'Clear all fields
                txt_usename.Text = ""
                txt_pwd.Text = ""

                'Focus on Username field
                txt_usename.Focus()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: USe parameters to avoid SQL injection. You should not store passwords in plain text - hash and salt are preferred.

Comment: use .Net SqlClient namespace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and `Import` the namespace for your Data provider so you dont have to type the entire name each time.

Comment: I will be Captain Obvious today and point out that this code `conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX-HP;Initial Catalog=eagleeyes;Integrated Security=True"` is missing an additional setting something of the like `Provider=SQLOLEDB;` and it is what the error message states - maybe you can read about ConnectionString arguments and it will solve your problem?

Comment: Downvote reason: read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

1) Imports system.data.sqlclient

2) Change Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection() **TO** Dim conn As New System.Data.sqlclient.sqlconnection

3) change Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql) **TO** Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(sql)